# How do I enable/disable a ribbon button in the Display form?

Tags: ribbon, display-form

I want to enable/disable a ribbon button in display form of a list based on whether versioning is enabled or not.

In the `EnabledScript` of `CommandUIHandler`, I am specifying a javascript function which will check the versioning in the given list.

The problem is that there seems to be no way of getting reference of the current list as tokens like `{ListId}` are not available in  `EnabledScript`. I also can't use `SP.ListOperation.Selection` as it reurns null, which is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListId` can be retrieved using `_spPageContextInfo.pageListId` in the display form of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code from EnabledScript will be executed on the page, You can fetch the name of the list from the `window.location.href` of the page. You can probably get the name by doing some string manipulations to the `window.location.href` by using `substr` or `substring` JS functions.

Example: Your `window.location.href` will be something like:

```
http://servername/Lists/YourList/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID="YoutItemId"
```

You can fetch "YourList" if you know that the "servername/Lists" and "Forms/DispForm.aspx" are going to be constant.

Another option is to check whether the window.location.href has the `Source` query string parameter. If it's present, it should directly give you the list url.

Comment: Hey Vardhaman, This can be one option but I am afraid this won't be an elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Did you check whether you have the "Source" query string parameter? If not, then I am afraid you will have to resort to the other option.

Comment: I do have the source parameter but the problem is I still have to do string manipulations as there is no method available in Client Object model which takes List Url as parameter, we can either use Title or GUID of the list.

Comment: Then I guess string manipulation is the only option you have. It will be easier with the "Source" parameter because you will have to fetch the string from the lastIndexOf("/")

Comment: Here is the solution: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/08/enabledisable-ribbon-button-in.html

Answer (score 0):

The default JavaScript context functions don't work? I.e.

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var currentListId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question SP.ListOperation.Selection returns null in the display page.

Comment: Must have overlooked that, sorry.